# Is it possible to determine if an empty query string is present in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails app / HTML5 app I need to redirect from

```
http://www.example.com/?
```

to a canonical:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

(The context is an HTML5 web app, where some browsers do not see the two URLs as equivalent, and will therefore request and cache two copies of the same page.)

I can't find any way of getting at the raw request string - `Request#original_fullpath()` and `Request#original_url()` have already removed the empty query string.

Comment: Have you try something simple in the controller like:     if request.path != root_path redirect_to root_path, status: :moved_permanently  end. The idea comes from: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Comment: request.path has already been stripped of any query string at that point.

Comment: So you want to make the redirect to happen at the routes level?

Comment: At any level. Even at the routes level request.original_fullpath lacks any indication that an empty query part was included in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull the raw url off of `request.env["REQUEST_URI"]`. This operates at the controller level, and is simply a delegate from rails to the underlying [Rack::Request](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L21).